# Discord.Net SocketMessage.Attachments is empty when I upload an image?

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I'm subscribing the `MessageReceived` event to check for uploaded images.
However when I send a message that contains nothing but an image, the bot receives no attachments nor any text.

```
private async Task Client_MessageReceived(SocketMessage arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg.Content); // Always prints an empty line
    Console.WriteLine(arg.Attachments.Count); // Always prints 0
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding `GatewayIntents.MessageContent` to the `DiscordSocketConfig` at startup.